# В профиле, в разделе "Избранное", добавить фильтрацию по меткам

Tags: предложение

Собственно.
Или может быть такое уже реализовано, а я не нашел?

П.С. Да, и вообще, найти что-то в "Избранном" очень сложно. Кроме фильтрации по меткам, можно было бы добавить поиск, хотя бы по заголовку вопроса.

Comment: Опубликовал фича-реквест на MSE [Synchronize search pattern with opened tab from the user activity panel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339610/339911)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать внутрисайтовым поиском с помощью ключевого слова `infavorites` (`infavorites:mine` или `user:id_пользователя`) и указания меток `[javascript]`, также можно добавить любые ключевые слова.

Подробнее в справке: [Как выполнять поиск?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Пример: [`infavorites:271553 [математика] *фрактал*`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A271553+%5B%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%5D+*%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB*)

Comment: Но иметь это в виде человекоудобного варианта на странице избранного было бы всё равно хорошо.